# How to replace old value with new value from next view controller in MKMapView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitextfield, mkmapview

I have two map View controllers, in first view controller i am fetching current location and auto filling some values and showing them in related textfields.

And in second view controller i am searching new location and sending its location values to first view controller using `DataEnteredDelegate` method now how to replace delegate method values in current location values in first view controller.

here i am getting second view controller values:

```
func userDidEnterInformation(info: [String]) {
    print("zoom map address viewcontroller data \(info)")
}
```

Prints: `zoom map address viewcontroller data '["560066", "Auto Nagar", "Bangalore"]'`

**how to replace** `560066` in `self.pincodeField.text` and `Auto Nagar` in `self.streetField.text` and `Bangalore` in `self.cityField.text` in first view controller

**first view controller code:**

```
class ProfileAddressViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, DataEnteredDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var pincodeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var cityField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var streetField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var storeNoField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var colonyField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var landmarkField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var latitude: String?
var logitude: String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self

        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=true;
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.triggerTouchAction(_:)))
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
@objc func triggerTouchAction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Please Help!")

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self

    viewController.zipName = self.pincodeField.text
    viewController.sublocalityName = self.colonyField.text
    viewController.localityName = self.cityField.text
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
}

func userDidEnterInformation(info: [String]) {
    print("zoom map address viewcontroller data \(info)")
}
@IBAction func submitButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewZoomAddressViewController") as! NewZoomAddressViewController;
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let _: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }

    let userLocation :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    latitude = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
    logitude = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
        if (error != nil){
            print("error in reverseGeocode")
        }
        let placemark = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]

        if placemark.count>0{
            let placemark = placemarks![0]
            print(placemark.administrativeArea!)
            print(placemark.country!)
            let placemarkDictonary: NSDictionary=placemark.addressDictionary as! NSDictionary
            self.pincodeField.text=placemarkDictonary["ZIP"] as? String
            self.cityField.text=placemarkDictonary["City"] as? String
            self.streetField.text=placemarkDictonary["Street"] as? String
            self.colonyField.text=placemarkDictonary["SubLocality"] as? String
            self.landmarkField.text=placemarkDictonary["SubThoroughfare"] as? String
        }
    }

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    // Drop a pin at user's Current Location
    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
    myAnnotation.title = "Current location"
    mapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .notDetermined:
        print("User still thinking")
    case .denied:
        print("User hates you")
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    case .authorizedAlways:
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    case .restricted:
        print("User dislikes you")
    }
}
}
```

**Next view controller code:**

```
protocol DataEnteredDelegate: class {
func userDidEnterInformation(info: [String])
}
class NewZoomAddressViewController: UIViewController {
weak var delegate: DataEnteredDelegate? = nil
var userModel : ProfileModel?

var zipName: String?
var localityName: String?
var sublocalityName: String?

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("in Zoom map VC")
    mapView.delegate = self
    addressLabel.text = "\(self.sublocalityName!) \(localityName!) \(self.zipName!)"
}

@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(info: [zipName!,sublocalityName!, localityName!])
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just set the values to your textfields in your `userDidEnterInformation(:)` func:

```swift
func userDidEnterInformation(info: [String]) {
   self.pincodeField.text = info[0]
   self.streetField.text = info[1]
   self.cityField.text = info[2]
}
```

However, accessing the String array subscripts with a number might lead to errors, I would suggest the following approach for you:

1. You should define something like a model for your returned information rather than using a String Array. I suggest you add the following struct somewhere:

```swift
struct DataEnteredModel {
   let pinCode: String
   let streetField: String
   let cityField: String
}
```

2. Change the function type in your delegate method from `func userDidEnterInformation(info: [String])` to `func userDidEnterInformation(info: DataEnteredModel)`
3. In `confirmBtn(_:9`, call the delegate function this way:

```swift
@IBAction func confirmBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    guard
        let zipName = zipName,
        let sublocalityName = sublocalityName,
        let localityName = localityName 
        else { return }
    let enteredData = DataEnteredModel(pinCode: zipName, streetField: sublocalityName, cityField: localityName)
    delegate?.userDidEnterInformation(info: enteredData)
}
```

4. Finally, in your `userDidEnterInformation` method in `ProfileAddressViewController` you have to do:

```swift
func userDidEnterInformation(info: DataEnteredModel) {
    self.pincodeField.text = info.pinCode
    self.streetField.text = info.streetField
    self.cityField.text = info.cityField
}
```

That should be it, in case of questions, feel free to ask!